# Chapter name in the toc

Tags: table-of-contents

I need the authors to be written in the table of contents before the chapter name. Moreover, the names of the authors are written in bold, and the chapter name in italics as in the photo.[image: simple]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[extrafontsizes,a4paper,twocolumn,*pt, openany]{memoir}
%%% Encodings and fonts %%%
\usepackage{iftex}[2013/04/04]
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}[2015/08/02]               % For advanced checking of different conditions
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table, hyperref, cmyk]{xcolor} % Probably a newer option, instead of the previous two lines. Conversion of all colors to cmyk is designed to meet the possible requirements of printing houses. Conversion to rgb is also possible.

\usepackage{polyglossia}[2014/05/21]             % Multilingual support (fontspec is loaded automatically)
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}  % The default language is Russian with support for nice commands from the babel package
\setotherlanguage{english}                       % Secondary language = English (American default)
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt{Courier New}
\ifXeTeX
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Mapping=tex-text}
\else
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\fi
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfontsf{Arial}  
\usepackage{cmap}                               % improved search for Russian words in the resulting pdf file
\defaulthyphenchar=127                          % If it is before fontenc, then hyphenation will not fit into the selected text when copied его в буфер обмена
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}[2014/04/30]         % Utf8 encoding



\usepackage{totcount}                             % Package for creating counters based on the last number of the item being counted (may require compiling the document twice)
\usepackage{totpages}                               % Hyperref compliant page count (refers to the last page number). It is desirable to put the last packet in the preamble

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
\if@twocolumn
\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
\else
\@restonecolfalse
\fi
\begin{otherlanguage}{russian}
    \chapter*{%
        \normalfont\textsf\LARGE\NoCaseChange{Content} 
    }%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
\end{otherlanguage}
\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
}
\newcommand{\addetoc}[2]{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}#2}%
}

\makeatother
\newcounter{headingalign}
\newcounter{pgnum}
\setcounter{pgnum}{1}              % 0 --- page numbers are not indicated in any way; 1 --- P. above page numbers (compile twice after change)
\settocdepth{chapter} %             to what level of subsections to place in the table of contents
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}         % to what level to number subsections
\setcounter{headingalign}{0}        %0 --- in the center; 1 --- left aligned


\renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}                % dotting to the page number of the beginning of the chapter / section

\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}        % non-bold page numbers for chapters in the table of contents
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftchapterdotsep}}% non-bold dots before page numbers for chapters in the table of contents
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\textsf}                       % lean chapter titles in the table of contents
\cftpagenumbersoff{part} %remove the page number for the part
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\bfseries\large}
\renewcommand*{\parttitlefont}{\textsf\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\partnamefont}{\textsf\large\bfseries}

\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\Huge\scshape\filright\centering}
{}
{20pt}
{}
\titlecontents{part}[0pt]{\addvspace{2pc}\centering\large\bfseries}{}{}{}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\PartTitle}{{Part Title}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\PartTitle}c

\newcommand{\firstchapter}{{First Chapter title}} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\firstchapter}
\newcommand{\secondchapter}{{Second Chapter title}} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\secondchapter}
\newcommand{\thirdchapter}{{Third Chapter title}} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\thirdchapter}

\begin{center}
    \tableofcontents
\end{center}   

\end{document}
```

what happened so far:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not process your MWE as given because I didn't have the fonts you were using, so I commented these out.

```
% memchaptocprob.tex  SE 568518

\documentclass[extrafontsizes,a4paper,twocolumn,*pt, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}  %% added by PW for some text
%%% Encodings and fonts %%%
\usepackage{iftex}[2013/04/04]
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}[2015/08/02]               % For advanced checking of different conditions
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table, hyperref, cmyk]{xcolor} % Probably a newer option, instead of the previous two lines. Conversion of all colors to cmyk is designed to meet the possible requirements of printing houses. Conversion to rgb is also possible.

\usepackage{polyglossia}[2014/05/21]             % Multilingual support (fontspec is loaded automatically)
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}  % The default language is Russian with support for nice commands from the babel package
\setotherlanguage{english}                       % Secondary language = English (American default)
%%%%%%%\setmonofont{Courier New}
%%%%%%%\newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt{Courier New}
\ifXeTeX
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Mapping=tex-text}
\else
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\fi
%%%%%%%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
%%%%%%\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}
%%%%%%%\setsansfont{Arial}
%%%%%%%\newfontfamily\cyrillicfontsf{Arial}  
\usepackage{cmap}                               % improved search for Russian words in the resulting pdf file
\defaulthyphenchar=127                          % If it is before fontenc, then hyphenation will not fit into the selected text when copied его в буфер обмена
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}[2014/04/30]         % Utf8 encoding



\usepackage{totcount}                             % Package for creating counters based on the last number of the item being counted (may require compiling the document twice)
\usepackage{totpages}                               % Hyperref compliant page count (refers to the last page number). It is desirable to put the last packet in the preamble

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
\if@twocolumn
\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
\else
\@restonecolfalse
\fi
\begin{otherlanguage}{russian}
    \chapter*{%
        \normalfont\textsf\LARGE\NoCaseChange{Content} 
    }%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
\end{otherlanguage}
\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
}
\newcommand{\addetoc}[2]{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}#2}%
}

\makeatother
\newcounter{headingalign}
\newcounter{pgnum}
\setcounter{pgnum}{1}              % 0 --- page numbers are not indicated in any way; 1 --- P. above page numbers (compile twice after change)
\settocdepth{chapter} %             to what level of subsections to place in the table of contents
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}         % to what level to number subsections
\setcounter{headingalign}{0}        %0 --- in the center; 1 --- left aligned


\renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}                % dotting to the page number of the beginning of the chapter / section

\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}        % non-bold page numbers for chapters in the table of contents
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftchapterdotsep}}% non-bold dots before page numbers for chapters in the table of contents
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\textsf}                       % lean chapter titles in the table of contents
\cftpagenumbersoff{part} %remove the page number for the part
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\bfseries\large}
\renewcommand*{\parttitlefont}{\textsf\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\partnamefont}{\textsf\large\bfseries}

\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\Huge\scshape\filright\centering}
{}
{20pt}
{}
\titlecontents{part}[0pt]{\addvspace{2pc}\centering\large\bfseries}{}{}{}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\PartTitle}{{Part Title}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\PartTitle}

\newcommand{\firstchapter}{{First Chapter title}} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\firstchapter}
\newcommand{\secondchapter}{{Second Chapter title}} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\secondchapter}
\newcommand{\thirdchapter}{\textbf{The authors} \textit{Third Chapter title}} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\thirdchapter}

\begin{center}
    \tableofcontents
\end{center}   

\chapter[\textbf{Author list} \textit{Title text}]{Whatever you want for the title}

\lipsum[1-7]  %% two pages of chapter text
\end{document}
```

At the end I changed your `\thirdchapter` macro to give the kind of entry you wanted in the ToC.

I have no idea how you want the chapter titles to look on the body of the document but I added a chapter that at least inserts what you want in the ToC.

Comment: thank you very much!!!